# How to pass data from a form in a view to another controller with C# MVC?

Tags: forms, post, model-view-controller, view, controller

If I have a form that needs to use a textbox input like as below:

```
@{
    if(IsPost){
      username = Request.Form["username"]
    }

}
    <form action="Home/Index" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="username" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

The controller is something like below,

```
 public class HomeController : Controller 
 {

      public ActionResult Index (string username) {

       if (string username != string.Empty)

         {
         Console.WriteLine("Your username is " + username);
         }

       return View();

      }
}
```

Seems like the data is not being passed from the post method. When I hit submit the URL that it requests is Home/Home/Index, which is not were the controller(HomeController) action is located, it should be Home/Index, and use the HomeController right?

What if I need to pass this data to a different controller that has an Index for the action, like UserController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance, you're missing a slash!

```
<form action="/Home/Index" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

But when using asp.net mvc, you should use Url.Content with the home directory character to ensure that if your site is deployed in a sub-directory of the site, the correct root will be found. So use:

```
<form action="@Url.Content("~/Home/Index")" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Oh wow, can't believe that! I fixed it by adding the missing slash. Though why use the Url.Content? Is this because when deployed under other sites, it won't find  /Home/Index or the Index file? Is Url.Content just more specific to locating that URL?

Comment: Yes, if you deploy in a subdir on a site such as www.site.com/MySite/Home/Index then just using /Home/Index will go to www.site.com/Home/Index missing off the MySite. Using Url.Content with ~/ will find your application root correctly.